# SharePoint Server 2019 on a 2003 functional level domain

Tags: active-directory, iis, sharepoint

I'm in a bit of a pickle. I just started at a new job, where the person I am replacing left in the middle of deploying a SharePoint server 2019 in a place with a 2003 functional level domain. The functional level of the domain is to allow machines running legacy OS (NT/2000 sort of a deal) to communicate with the DC.

I got the SharePoint server to sync user profiles from the domain controller using a "User Profile Service Application" sync tool. But this didn't help in authenticating as the IIS 10 front end still fails to authenticate with the 2003 level domain controller to pass this identity to the SharePoint site. Unfortunately IIS is not my strong point and I'm a bit lost.

I guess the core of the question is how do you get IIS 10 to communicate to a 2003 level domain controller?

I really appreciate your time reading this and thank you for any ideas, strings of curse words for me missing something simple are also appreciated - I would love to be dumb right now!

Comment: Are you sure it's a functional level problem? This doc seems to be saying that 2003 (native) is supported - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-2019

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely a 2003 functional level. I just synced it with SharePoint and used non-kernel based login with forms. It's definitely authenticating but hits an unexpected error on login. 

Thanks for doing better research than me, it seems this is fully supported - I mused have messed up configuring.